# Translating old charm to modern language

Tags: early-modern-english, comprehension

> About six or seven years ago, Chattox did fall out with one Hugh Moore
>   of Pendle, as aforesaid, about certain cattle of Moore's, which Moore
>   did charge Chattox to have bewitched: for which Chattox did curse and
>   worry Moore, and said she would be revenged of Moore: whereupon Moore
>   presently fell sick, and languished about half a year, and then died.
>   Which Moore upon his death-bed said, that Chattox had bewitched him to
>   death.
>
> About six years ago, a daughter of Anne Chattox, called
>   Elizabeth, having been at the house of John Nutter of the Bull-hole,
>   to beg or get a dish full of milk, which she had, and brought to her
>   mother, who was about a field's breadth of Nutter's house, which her
>   mother  Anne Chattox took and put into a can, and did charm **the same**
>   with two sticks across in the same field: whereupon John Nutter son
>   came unto her, Chattox, and misliking her doings, put the can and milk
>   over with his foot; and the morning next after, a cow of John Nutter
>   fell sick, and so languished three or four days, and then died.

This is text from The Wonderfull Discoverie of Witches in the Countie of Lancaster (1612).
Since it's archaic, I'm having the difficulty of understanding it. Especially for bolded 'the same'. What does it refer to here? Is it the Nutter's house?

Comment: In contemporary English, BrE or AmE, this is only legal or administrative (law) usage.https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/229644/use-of-the-same/229684#229684

Answer (score 4):

It's certainly not Old English; from the date it's [Early Modern English](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_Modern_English) (Old English is almost incomprehensible to a native speaker of modern English).

What you're having trouble with is a rambling run-on sentence, and it's unhelpful in the ways it refers to previous things. For example in "...Nutter's house, which her mother...", the *which* seems to refer to the house, but it must refer to the dish of milk, as putting a house in a can seems implausible.

*The same* isn't widely used like this in everyday British or American English*, but isn't completely unknown, and it's fairly common in Indian English. Instead we would use simply *it* when referring to objects. *The same* is rarer with people, and would be replaced with *her*/*them*/*him*.

We know that Nutter's son kicked over the can and milk when he saw Anne making the charm with the sticks, so we can assume that *the same* refers to the can of milk.

---

* It is used in legal settings.

Comment: It's very much still used in legal language.

Comment: @Lambie I thought as much, hence the insertion of "everyday".  In the technical writing with which I'm familiar it would never be seen, but I half remembered seeing it in contracts and patents